# How can I make my service deployed locally visible for a Google Home device app?

Tags: google-home

I've created my action on Google development project and I've deployed a self signed service locally(in the local network) which I've added for fulfilment on the Action settings. Now I see my app in the Google Assistant, under Add devices, but when I try to link accounts(the account linking was also set previously), the action.devices.SYNC is not triggered and I get the "Couldn't update the settings. Check your connection". My phone is also in the same network. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

All Google Assistant Actions, including Smart Home Actions, go through Google's cloud. Even requests from your phone or Google Home device to the smart device on the same LAN go through Google's servers.

Google's servers need to be able to contact your local service, so it needs to have a globally accessible IP address/name.